# DateFormatter returns wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I did an extension for Date that returns a formatted string:

```
extension Date {
    var myFormattedDate : String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, y (HH:mm a)"
        return formatter.string(for: self)!
    }
}
```

On runtime, I set a breakpoint inside the `myFormattedDate` property.

`po self` printed:

> 2017-09-05 **08:50**:00 +0000

`po formatter.string(for: self)!` printed:

> Tuesday, September 5, 2017 **(11:50 AM)**"

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Printing a `Date` always returns an **UTC time**, regardless of the local time zone. Just avoid printing a `Date` object directly if you want to see the date with the proper time zone in your console.

Comment: Im not printing the date object, first I'm using `DateFormatter` and getting a wrong time from it. as you can see in my example above.